# tools to work with json and curl from the console

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I'm giving my first steps with ElasticSearch and to test things I'm currently working with curl from the command line.  However it's kind of annoying because I have to type everything on a text editor and paste in the console (no tab formatting in the console), and the json output you get is not formatted.

So I was wondering if there's some equivalente of the many sql consoles for working with json data, to make it easier to test and play around with json rest web services.

What tools do you use for this kind of tasks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, if the json output you get isn't formatted, append `?pretty=1` to any url. The result will be much nicer. Another option is to pipe the output to `python -m json.tool` if you have Python 2.6+.  I like the latter option because I have it saved to a shell function and can simply type `| j` after any command that outputs json.  Much shorter and generic.

For issuing curl commands there are a couple of options. The most universal solution is to create a shell script with the whole command. For example:

```
curl -s localhost:9200/foo/_search -d'
  {"query":
     {"query_string":
        {"query":"foo*"}}}' | python -m json.tool
```

Rather than pasting that at a shell prompt, save it in a file.  Then just tweak the source and run it as often as you need.

```
% sh query
```

A variation on this is to use Emacs.  I use it to run `curl` on regions of buffers, manipulate the result, etc. `shell-command-on-region` or `M-|` is a good choice there.  So for the above script, I can issue `M-| sh RET` instead of switching to a shell.  Vim allows you to do something similar.

I haven't checked this one out, but a lot of people seem to like elasticsearch-head.  It's a UI that will issue queries and give you structured results.  http://mobz.github.com/elasticsearch-head/

**Update**: I recently noticed that Perl's JSON module ships with a handy command-line utility called `json_pp` that function's similarly to Python's `json.tool`.  If you install `JSON::XS` there's also a (faster) `json_xs` bin.

Comment: very good answer, lots of useful tips, BTW I am already using head and it's a wonderful tool

Answer (score 4):

I've found another tool that seems pretty handy

http://stedolan.github.com/jq/tutorial/

```
curl ideasba.org/api/ideas/1 | jq .

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   525  100   525    0     0    990      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2488
{
  "created": "2012-09-22T05:20:00Z",
  "author": {
    "nickname": "opensas",
    "created": "2012-09-22T01:40:00Z",
    "id": 2,
...
```

It's got several options to work with json, like filtering

```
curl ideasba.org/api/ideas/1 | jq .votes
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   525  100   525    0     0    809      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2441
{
  "neg": 1,
  "pos": 8
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/micha/jsawk is the best solution.

JSAWK and Resty rules :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the [Sense plugin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense/doinijnbnggojdlcjifpdckfokbbfpbo).  It gives you intelligent autocomplete, JSON syntax checking and tidying, and pretty syntax-highlighted output. It's being actively developed, and is the tool I choose when I want to demonstrate requests in talks.

Comment: That's not remotely console based.