# Splitting JSON String Array in Bash

Tags: arrays, json, string, bash

What's the easiest way to download and split the contents of

http://code.dlang.org/available

into a string array in Bash?

I then want to use this to provide completion for a bash commnd.

Comment: http://trentm.com/json/ , https://github.com/micha/jsawk , http://stedolan.github.io/jq/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373381/tools-to-work-with-json-and-curl-from-the-console

Comment: Nice, but I would like to, if possible, only use the Bash builtins together with wget/curl for the download.

Comment: using only bash builtins, the answer is that you probably don't want to do that. You can write something that does the job badly, but writing a fully compliant JSON parser -- something which can differentiate escaped quotes from unescaped ones, for instance -- is probably a much larger project than the tool you're thinking of using this for. Moreover, since bash doesn't support nested data structures, if you _did_ go to the effort of writing a fully compliant native parser, it would be of very little use; you couldn't round-trip with it, for instance.

Comment: If you're targeting an operating system that has modern bash, it probably also has modern Python, and if it has modern Python, it has a `json` module. Why not use that to convert the content into something bash can easily process -- like a NUL-delimited list?

Comment: Your'e right, I'll go with Python all the way for downloading and parsing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, parsing deep JSON strings is a job for an dedicated JSON parser, but some simple cases (like this) is can be reduced to *extracting quoted parts* from an string and this can be done easily with `grep` such:

```
data=($(curl -s 'http://code.dlang.org/available' | grep -oP '[,\s"]+\K.*?(?=")'))
printf "%s\n" ${data[@]}
```

prints

```
zeal
arsd
cookbook
...
...
log4d
dvorm
dfl
```

Ps: It doesn't handles escaped `\"` but probably *in this case* it doesn't hurts.